# How to parse data to and from cobol s9(6)v99 format in java

Tags: java, parsing, cobol

I am sending and recieving a products information from a server as a String, the server receive and send the price of the product in COBOLS **s9(6)v99** format.I am unable to convert the given decimal from or to this format in java.

COBOL s9(6)V99 format exmaples:

- 0000016H
- 0000000{

**Note**: Currently I have no implementation of the conversion,I am looking for a solution

Comment: So would you mind giving some example of the data to parse? I guess 99,9% of users here have never used COBOL!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257771/how-to-format-a-number-to-s95v99-ascii-in-net

Comment: i have read that discussion and it concludes to nowhere...

Comment: In what format are you receiving the data? string, binary, integers?

Comment: I am sending and receiving data in string format

Comment: Edit that into your question, also add a code sample what you currently have where you parse the cobol string to java object, and java object to cobol string.

Comment: At first sight I think you have an encoding problem, not a parsing problem. `S9(6)V99` means that you should expect to receive a signed 8 digit field and that there is an implied decimal point after the first 6 digits. So, if you receive +12345678, that should be interpreted as +123456.78. The fact you are receiving data such as `0000016H` means that either your data layout in your java code does not match the Cobol data layout, or that the data has been encoded with a different character set.

Comment: It looks like some screwed-up version of a Packed Decimal (Comp-3). The S at the beginning means it is a signed number. If it is PD then the last character should be C (+) or D(-).

Comment: At a second glance it does actually look like Zoned Decimal. Thus the first number is +168 and the second one is -0 (?).

Comment: So, get the sender to send it in a format where you don't have to do any coding. Chose what is convenient for you (in a fixed-width field) and it is a very minor change to the COBOL program.

Comment: @theblitz that's not a negative zero.

Comment: And where is your data coming from? A Mainframe?

Comment: @BillWoodger Yeah. My bad. My knowledge of the EBCDIC character set is kinda rusty. Thought { was D0 not C0.

Comment: @BillWoodger i can not force the server to change the format, actually it is a insurance clearing house(switch) with which i am communicating.

Comment: @DaveH i have checked the guide provided by the server, the data is encoded in **s9(6)v99**, and it is not corrupted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Suggestions

In general

- Change the Cobol. If the cobol was changed to `s9(6)V99 sign leading` it would be a lot easier to handle in java. In your case, this is probably not an option
- If you can get the **Cobol Copybook** use a package

#### Packages

If you can get the **Cobol Copybook**, why not use one of the Cobol / Java packages

- [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/)
- [Cobol2J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cobol2j/)
- **Legstar**
- **IBM** has software for this

**Note:** Even if you do not have the Full Cobol Copybook, you could set up a Cobol Copybook for this one field and still use a package. The copybook would be:

```
   01  MY-REC.
       03 FIELD-1              PIC S9(6)V99.
```

#### What you need to know

There is no one single Cobol Zoned Decimal format, it varies from compilere to Compiler and
what the encoding is. To decode `Zoned Decimal` you really need to know the

- The Cobol Compiler
- The Encoding used on the Server

In this case I would guess it is

- IBM Compiler running on IBM Mainframe or AS400
- US Ebdic (IBM037) or something similar (definitely not German EBCDIC (IBM273))

#### Interpretting Zoned decimal

In Zoned decimal:

- **S** indicates it is a signed number; the sign will be `overpunched` on the last numeric digit.
- **9** represents a single digit
- **V** represents an `assumed` decimal place

So `s9(6)V99` is a signed number with 6 digits before the decimal place + 2 after

#### Effect of Encoding

The `encoding` (characterset) used by the server determines how the sign digit is represented.
For US (and UK) Ebcdic +0/-0 are `{ / }` but they are different for German Ebcdic.
For ASCII servers it is different again

#### Java Code

The ebcdic conversion code (note it still needs to be adjusted for the assumed decimal):

```
private static int positiveDiff = 'A' - '1';
private static int negativeDiff = 'J' - '1';

private static char positive0EbcdicZoned = '{';
private static char negative0EbcdicZoned = '}';

public static String fromZoned(String numZoned) {
    String ret;
    String sign = "";
    char lastChar, ucLastChar;

    if (numZoned == null || ((ret = numZoned.trim()).length() == 0) || ret.equals("-")) {
        return "";
    }

    lastChar = ret.charAt(ret.length() - 1);
    ucLastChar = Character.toUpperCase(lastChar);


    switch (ucLastChar) {
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
    case 'D':
    case 'E':
    case 'F':
    case 'G':
    case 'H':
    case 'I':
        lastChar = (char) (ucLastChar - positiveDiff);
        break;
    case 'J':
    case 'K':
    case 'L':
    case 'M':
    case 'N':
    case 'O':
    case 'P':
    case 'Q':
    case 'R':
        sign = "-";
        lastChar = (char) (ucLastChar - negativeDiff);
        break;
    default:
        if (lastChar == positive0EbcdicZoned) {
            lastChar = '0';
        } else if (lastChar == negative0EbcdicZoned) {
            lastChar = '0';
            sign = "-";
        }           
    }
    ret = sign + ret.substring(0, ret.length() - 1) + lastChar;

    return ret;
}
```

To set `+0/-0` characters

```
public static void setDefaultEbcidicCharacterset(String charset) {
    if (getHold(charset).isEbcdic) {
        byte[] b = {(byte) 0xC0, (byte) 0xD0};
        String s = new String(b, charset);
        if (s.length() == 2) {
            positive0EbcdicZoned = s.charAt(0);
            negative0EbcdicZoned = s.charAt(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

An alternative way to derive the sign (for EBCDIC encoding) is to convert the sign back into the raw bytes:

```
private static final byte HIGH_NYBLE = (byte) 0xf0;
private static final byte ZONED_NEGATIVE_NYBLE_VALUE = (byte) 0xD0;

    String Sign = "";
    byte signByte = signStr.getBytes(encoding)[0];
    if (((byte) (signByte & HIGH_NYBLE)) == ZONED_NEGATIVE_NYBLE_VALUE) {
        sign = "-";
    }
    byte lastDigitBytes = (byte) (signByte | HIGH_NYBLE);
```

---

#### ASCII Cobols

In this case it is EBCDIC. For ASCII based cobols it is different again. This is [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) generic conversion class for Ascii Zoned-Decimal:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/code/HEAD/tree/jrecord/Source/JRecord_Common/src/net/sf/JRecord/Types/TypeFjZoned.java

**Note:** I am the author JRecord

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it should be reasonably straightforward. This assumes, which seems to be the case from your example, that this is a Zoned Decimal.

First you will need to get the sign of the number. Simply check the last character. If it is a non-digit then it is negative (assuming you are using F format for the positive number).
Once you have that you can then replace that character with the correct, equivalent digit.

You now have a string representation of a number.

Now do

```
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(theInputString)
```

then divide by 100 and re-apply the sign.
You could also just add the sign as a "-" or "+" to the string before calling valueOf.

Comment: "using F format for the positive number" is less common than you might think.

Comment: Since I was typing at the same time, very much less common than you think. Certainly for most COBOL systems it would be a potentially very, very, bad thing. It also indicates shoddiness.

Comment: Long time since I programmed in Cobol. Nevertheless, the idea still stands.

Comment: @theblitz can you please describe that what "H" and "{" means here

Comment: A couple of links that will explain it better than I can: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~byrnes/csci360/notes/360dec.htm https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/z1265705.htm

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to have cobol in the server move the values into a screen variable like

```
77 S-VALUE PIC  ------9,99
```

and export this variable which is easily readable and can be parsed into a Java double variable with:

```java
Double value = Double.parseDouble(string);
```

or

```java
Double value = new Double(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case its for IBM COBOL, the [JZOS Record Generator](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/record-generator/3.0?topic=what-is-record-generator-java) with SYSADATA output from the z/OS COBOL compiler can be used to generate a Java Class representing COBOL structures and the getter and setter methods doing the conversions. Its binary (bitwise) compatible to the datatypes/structures in COBOL.
It can be downloaded for free but requires an IBM ID. For compile outside z/OS the ibmjzos.jar is required, which is part of the JDK for z/OS.